# When does exec cause a PID switch?

Tags: shell, perl, exec

My boss wrote some code (I know - dangerous territory) in Perl years ago, and now it's causing a problem - the PID changes, so the pidfile is no longer valid. Code:

```
exec($0, "-f", "$configfile")
```

*I* think there may be a shell invocation involved that is forking $0 (cloning probably), but he's 1000% sure there's no shell involved. Is there another explanation for another process (a different PID) instead of an actual exec'd program in the same PID, for the code above?

BTW

```
exec("exec", $0, "-f", "$configfile")
```

works fine (the exec'd process has the same PID as before the exec function call).

Also, if there is a shell involved, how can I prove to him that that's the case?

Comment: `exec( $^X, $0, "-f", $configfile )` is better. Actually, simply modifying `@ARGV` instead of using `exec` is probably better.

Comment: The code you posted is probably not representative of the problem. You're probably not using the `exec` builtin as what you posted would imply. You need to edit your question to include the required minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: A process does not magically change its PID. From the [perldocs on exec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#exec-LIST): _If there is more than one argument in LIST, this calls execvp(3) with the arguments in LIST_, so the net effect is what [execvp](http://man.he.net/man3/execvp) is doing here, but it does [not change the pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866615/execvp-appears-to-change-pid-of-the-process). Basically the current image is replaced by what is in $0. In a normal situation, this would again the same perl image but his is not necessarily the case. You need to check $0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fork, because `exec` receives 3 arguments. From `perldoc -f exec`:

> If there is more than one argument in LIST, this calls execvp(3)
> with the arguments in LIST

Comment: There may not be a fork, but there's *something* causing a new pid - that's what I need to know - what that something is.

Comment: What's executing the code in the first place? Where does the pid file come from?

Comment: In a very stupid way - after invocation of the perl script, a pgrep is used to capture the pid as it is at the time of invocation (or technically, a little later). It's a SysV init script in a systemd environment.

Comment: My Perl is a bit rusty; is there a significant difference between `exec($0, "-f", $configfile)` and `exec $0, "-f", $configfile` here?

Comment: Shouldn't be. Perl likes both.

Comment: @chpner, No. __

Comment: Note that this answer does not hold true on Windows.

Comment: @Larry You're using a shell command to pgrep the pid for the current perl program? What's wrong with using [`$$`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$PROCESS_ID)?

Answer (score 4):

When you pass multiple arguments to `system` or `exec`, no shell is used. This contract is broken on Windows, where a shell is used if the program can't be executed without one.

When you use the block form of `system` or `exec`, no shell is used. Not even on Windows.

---

There's talk in the comments of `exec` creating a new process. That is not the case (outside of Windows).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.14;

say "$$ @ARGV";

if ( !@ARGV ) {
   exec( $^X, "--", $0, "foo" )
      or die "exec: $!";
}
```

```
$ ./a
865
865 foo
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this is Linux, not Windows.

Comment: I would have answered exactly the same if you had.

Comment: OK, so no shell. How does a new pid get assigned?

Comment: Comments are not the place for new questions. This question is about `exec`, which does not create a new process.

Comment: Empirically, it does in this case.

Comment: No, something else is.

Comment: Cool - is there something I can look for that might show that?

Comment: Comments are not the place for new questions.